# Why i can't launch a browser with this script

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python 
and I'm trying to open chrome in a background mode
I tried it with path "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
but nothing is happening I always get a error

```
import os
import subprocess
path = subprocess.Popen(['cd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for line in path.stdout:
 continue
path.wait()
paths = (str(line).strip()) + "\chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://www.google.com"
os.system(paths)
```

Comment: why not try to compose your chrome command in an arglist with `subprocess` instead of `os.system` ? and use raw prefix to take care of escaping backslashes

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think the intent of `cd` here is to print out the current directory. (Though I don't personally know whether it actually does that on Windows.)

Comment: yes you're right, it's the idea, and it works. Well `os.getcwd()` is better :) and it doesn't even print anything...

Comment: @johnashu why did you delete your answer? it didn't explain the issue but seemed to a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that when you compose your command line, it doesn't work because of the path with spaces being interpreted as separate arguments.

What will work is to run the command using raw strings, using `subprocess` to compose the argument line, like this:

```
import subprocess
command = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
subprocess.check_call([command,"--headless","--disable-gpu","--remote-debugging-port=9222","http://www.google.com"])
```

`subprocess` has the argument list, so it can quote the ones needing to be quoted, like the main command.